# Can I hide a null part of an AngularJS expression?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object that has 3 fields:

```
obj.firstName
obj.middleName
obj.lastName
```

I have an array (objArray) of these objects that I am showing in an ng-repeat like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objArray">
    <td>{{ obj.lastName + ", " + obj.firstName + " " + obj.middleName }}</td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that I have some obj's that have null as a value for obj.middleName.  Is there a way to not display null if part of the expression happens to be null?  I see that you can use a filter to remove one element completely from the ng-repeat, but I still want to display an element that has firstName and lastName.  I just want it so that it doesn't display like this:

Smith, John null

But rather just displays this:

Smith, John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join`

```
 <td>{{ [obj.lastName + ',' ,obj.firstName, obj.middleName].join(' ') }}</td>
```

**JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/21495/**

Comment: This is perfect and simple, I had never used join() before but this is great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the parts in concern with a `span` with a `ng-if`. If it's null, the span will remove itself from the DOM.

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objArray">
    <td>{{ obj.lastName + ", " + obj.firstName }}<span ng-if="obj.middleName ">{{" " + obj.middleName }}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a function on scope that takes as an argument one of your objects which then handles if any of the fields are null. This reduces the amount of template logic and keeps that "logic" in the controller rather than the specific view (template). Then you can use a `span` and an `ng-bind` expression that gets set to the return value of your function.

```
/* HTML */
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objArray">
    <td><span ng-bind="getDisplayName(obj)"></span></td>
</tr>


/* JS */
$scope.getDisplayName = function getDisplayName(obj) {
    var name = "";
    if (!obj) {
        return name;
    }

    if (obj.lastName) {
        name += obj.lastname + ", ";
    }

    if (obj.firstName) {
        name += obj.firstName + " ";
    }

    if (obj.middleName) {
        name += obj.middleName
    }

    return name;
}
```